# Can't execute submit button on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to use button with submit type with assigned function to it. Whenever I try to do this using Safari, page reloads. Like the function is not assigned to the button. I checked all of other browers and there is no issue anywhere else.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./Chat.css";
import Message from "./message/Message";
import db from "../../firebase/firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { selectChatId, selectChatName } from "../../store/chatSlice";
import { selectUser } from "../../store/userSlice";
import FlipMove from "react-flip-move";

function Chat() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const chatId = useSelector(selectChatId);
  const chatName = useSelector(selectChatName);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatId) {
      db.collection("chats")
        .doc(chatId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setMessages(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        });
    }
  }, [chatId]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("chats").doc(chatId).collection("messages").add({
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      message: inputValue,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photo: user.photo,
      email: user.email,
    });
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <div className="chat__header">
        <h4>
          To: <span className="chat__userName">{chatName}</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div className="chat__messages">
        <FlipMove>
          {messages.map(({ id, data }) => (
            <Message key={id} content={data} />
          ))}
        </FlipMove>
      </div>
      <div className="chat__messageInput">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder={"Message"}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            disabled={!chatId}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="chat__messageInputButton"
            onClick={sendMessage}
            disabled={!chatId}
          ></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

I've never met with problem like this and I have no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use the onSubmit event:

```
return (
      <form onSubmit={yourSubmitFunction}>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

When a button has `type='submit'`, it will attempt to submit form data to the server. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

What you can do is prevent the default event with `event.preventDefault()`.

I added an example code snippet below, run the code snippet and when you click the button it will trigger an alert instead of a page reload.

```js
const ButtonComponent = () => {

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    alert('clicked!');
  }

  return (
    <button type='submit' onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Click me</button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ButtonComponent/>,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need that submit type, because I need it to react on enter pressed. There isn't any displayed button, it's hidden and put inside an input. so i guess I can't change it to type='button'. Or I don't understand something?

Comment: @larryfisherman ah I see, I updated my code snippet. I believe what you'll want to do is prevent the default event with `event.preventDefault()`